# Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Вместе с тем, что касается уплотнительной техники, мы увидели новую ситуацию на рынке.

Мне кажется, здесь пропущено "то" и поэтому можно поставить тире... Или я неправа?

Вместе с тем, что касается уплотнительной техники — мы увидели новую ситуацию на рынке.

Answer (score 1):

А если так: "Вместе с тем что касается уплотнительной техники, мы увидели новую ситуацию на рынке". По аналогии: "в то же время если говорить об уплотнительной технике..."

"Вместе с тем" - это наречное выражение, оно не обособляется. Будем считать, что наречие относится к союзу.

Тогда тире возможно только как авторский знак, здесь хватит и запятой.

Comment: София полностью права!!!

Comment: Уважаемая София, мне кажется, Вы тут не правы. Вместе с тем - это не наречное выражение, а союз (как пишет запятание). А при встрече двух подчинительных союзов или подчинительного союза и союзного слова на стыке между ними ставится запятая, если возможно изъятие придаточного предложения без нарушения структуры главного. Здесь придаточное предложение (или конструкция) "что касается уплотнительной техники" может быть изъята, поэтому делаем вывод, что запятая все-таки нужна. Открытым остался вопрос с тире...